# If input text equals to "string" then multiply $scope.number with 0.2 - AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I just read about AngularJS a while ago and I was able to get some things done. Total newbie here. But this one, I just can't get past it. I read around stackoverflow and understand that there are NO if statements in AngularJS.

I read about ng-switch, ng-change, ng-if and tried everything but still doesn't work. I simply want an input text that when "test" is typed, a variable changes its value.

```
<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <input type="text" ng-model="test" ng-change="change()"  /> 
    counter = {{number}}
  </div>
</div>

function Controller($scope) {
  $scope.number = 1000;
  $scope.change = function() {
    $scope.number = $scope.number * 0.2; 
  };
}
```

This must be a stupid question, but here's a fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/e68mx/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to test it with an if statement.

```
$scope.change = function() {
   if($scope.test === 'test') {
      $scope.number *= 0.2;
   }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess the whole "no if statements in angularjs" misled me.

Comment: I'm confused by you comment, there are if statements - it's javascript after all.  Not sure where you picked this up from.

Answer (score -1):

Prefer `$watch` over `ng-change`. <del>The reason is that `ng-change` runs before the model is actually updated in many cases (all? I am not sure).</del> See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fCymg/

Comment: You really shouldn't use $watch outside of directives. $watches are made to be processed on every $digest to assist in blindly binding data from your model to the DOM. ng-change will be processed (during a digest, by a $watch) only when the input's model is changed.

Comment: Thank you for your attempt to help.

Comment: @blesh Do you have an official reference that discourages the usage of `$scope.$watch` in _controllers_ or are you just misinformed?

Comment: Nothing "official", although there should be... there's absolutely no reason to ever use a $watch in a controller, and I'd challenge anyone to come up with one scenario where a $watch is going to be more efficient than an event binding. an event is always going to be more efficient. $watches are harder to test, as they require a $digest.

Comment: Furthermore: Every $watch added slows down your $digest, which is what updates your view "real time". ng-change doesn't add a $watch at all, and instead is called within a chain triggered by the same $watch ngModel uses. Thus making it more efficient. The source is on github if you'd like to confirm this.

I did downvote your answer, but only because you said to "prefer $watch to ngChange" which just isn't right. If you can either change your answer, or come up with some "official" reasoning of your own, I'll be happy to change my vote.

Comment: Of course there is nothing official. Because it simply is perfectly OK (and endorsed - or else there would certainly be a warning somewhere in the docs) to use $watches. Definitely with caution, but this holds true for every bit of code you write. So the "shouldn't use $watch outside of directives" claim is absolutely unsupported (especially the "outside directives" part). --- Btw the answer does suffer in the part that ng-change runs after model change, I think I confused this.